# ngAnimate not adding animation classes on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, animation

I've included `angular-animate.js`:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

And added it as a dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate'  
])
```

I created a `ng-repeat` list:

```
<li ng-repeat="result in search.results" class="movie-list__item list-animation">
  ...        
</li>
```

And defined `.list-animation`:

```
.list-animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.list-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Why is it not working? It seems that `ngAnimate` is not putting animation-related classes into any element.

**AngularJS:** `1.2.6`
**angular-animate**: `1.2.9`

Comment: Creating a jsffidle'd help a lot in this case. It's hard to see what the problem is without seeing the problem in action

Answer (score -3):

```
<li ng-repeat="result in search.results" class="movie-list__item list-animation">
```

should be

```
<li ng-repeat="result in search.results" class="movie-list__item list-animation" ng-animate>
```